# Is it true or false : p↔q does not imply p→¬q?

Tags: logic

**Problem is :**

---

> Let p and q be propositions. Using only the Truth Table, decide
>   whether
>
> ```
>                      p↔q does not imply p→¬q
> ```
>
> is True or False.

---

**I try to explain :**

---

Rule of inference "*if the premises hold, then the conclusion holds.*"

Premise#1
  Premise#2
        ...
  Premise#n
 (then) Conclusion

P→Q  ,and
   Q→P
 then P→(Q)'    (conclusion).
It is not tautology , so "*does not*" should be True.

---

*What I'm asking*: Is my approach correct ? If not , then what is solution ?

---

**Edited** :

```
p   q   p↔q p→¬q    (p↔q)→(p→¬q)
0   0   1   1           1
0   1   0   1           1
1   0   0   1           1
1   1   1   0           0
```

So, "*imply*" is FALSE making "*does not imply*" TRUE.

Comment: Your approach doesn’t answer the question: you’re supposed to use **only the truth table**.

Comment: Please , check : _Are my solutions correct?_

Comment: Yes, it looks fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution (after edited) is correct (and I think it's a good approach to include partial's of the expression under investigation). The point one have to take is that you have to consider the meaning of the phrase "does not imply":

The first thought maybe that "$A$ does not imply $B$" means $\neg(A\Rightarrow B)$, but that's normally not what it means. It normally means that $A\Rightarrow B$ is not always true. It's the latter meaning you have used in your truth table.

Perhaps one should not categorically state that $(p \Leftrightarrow q) => (p \Rightarrow\neg q)$ is false, becase the truth tables states that under some circumstances it's true.

Comment: (p⇔q)=>(p⇒¬q) is contingency but not valid , rt ?

Comment: +1 for "It normally means that A⇒B is not always true."